# JDK location was moved to Gradle Settings Android Studio 2022.3.1.18 Version

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 2022.3.1.18 Version. I am getting this error in this version. JDK location moved to Gradle Can't change settings

`* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.`

[image]

[image]

JDK location moved to Gradle Can't change settings. I can't find its place in the version I'm using. can you help me ?

Comment: Android dev toolings always break something after updates, at this point the safest and least time consuming to do is to wait some time before doing an update that just came out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to install JDK 11 then after move on to `Android Studio` **settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle** The Select Java 11 From `Gradle JDK` Dropdown

[image: jdk]

Comment: This figure is blank for me, what is the reason? https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEFcd.png

Comment: which is your Android Studio Version

Comment: 2022.3.1.18 https://imgur.com/qvs33yV

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> Change JDK Location to the Java 11 jdk folder

[image: df]

Comment: 2022.3.1.18 version does not have that screen you showed
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euuyf.png
Does this photo come out at the location you mentioned?

Comment: i think you are not able to find it properly. because these are the ways which is working

Answer (score 0):

Just download it and install newest version (or v17 if you prefer long term support version) from the [Oracle site](https://www.oracle.com/es/java/technologies/downloads/). Make sure to setup the path variables correctly depending on your system.

Comment: version with v17 installed

Comment: Android Studio already includes the necessary Java 17 version. That version should be used.